# Why would I want to dispose of sharks?

Tags: shark-game

Early in the game, a grotto is unlocked where I can dispose of my various resources, including sharks. Is there any benefit to doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are eventually resources that will require others to operate.  One such example is the auto-transmuter, which will transform crystal into sharkonium.  If your crystal production speed is low, this can cause you to deplete your stockpile and keep you from getting more.  The way to fix this is to dispose of some auto-transmuters until your crystal production is in the positives.

Other than something like that, there does not appear to be a reason to dispose or resources.

Comment: I'm still only at the Strange Gate, but wondered if I'd missed something (it's enabled so early in the game). Wondered if it was a reset/prestige type thing but too scared to click.

Comment: @fredley I couldn't find anything in the game's code that uses disposal for any reason.  There is a prestige resource you get from entering the gate.